# Docker build runs 2nd stage before the 1st

Tags: node.js, docker, ubuntu

I'm following this [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds) to write a multi-stage build.

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install apt-transport-https -y
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y

FROM node:alpine
COPY . ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm run lighthouse
```

I'm trying to install Google Chrome onto the image before running Google Lighthouse. However, according to the logs, the build runs the 2nd stage first.

```
 => CACHED [stage-1 2/4] COPY . ./                                                                                   0.0s 
 => [stage-1 3/4] RUN npm install                                                                                  100.8s
 => ERROR [stage-1 4/4] RUN npm run lighthouse
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: The second stage doesn’t use anything from the first, so they can be built in parallel. What behavior were you expecting?

Comment: @jakub thanks for replying. so how should i have written the dockerfile?

Comment: Why not install Google chrome in the node image? Also, you can’t mix programs between Ubuntu and alpine. They are not compatible.

Comment: To expand on @jakub's point, you're installing Chrome in one image and then installing your application in a second image.  Nothing is shared between the two images unless you explicitly `COPY --from` one image to the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are running parallel, cause neither of the stages depend on eachother.. If you are doing this just to understand multi stage builds in docker; Here is a sample:

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install apt-transport-https -y
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install google-chrome-stable -y

FROM someangularapp:alpine as builder
COPY . ./
RUN npm install
RUN ng build 

##Above stage generates a `dist` folder in its workspace

FROM nginx:latest as deployer
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/
```

Now whenever you run:
`docker build -t someimagename --target deployer .`

The builder stage executes before deployer stage... because deployer uses `--from=builder` which means it has a dependecy on builder stage to copy some files in this case.